# Is it possibly to forward mail in phpbb?

Tags: email, phpbb

I want to forward all mails sent to the administrator account to another e-mail-address. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPbb does not handle incoming mail - your MTA does (postfix, sendmail, exim, etc.). You'll need to configure the forwarding in whatever MTA you have running.